# Search value in a functor's c'tor

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, functor

Say I had a `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::vector<int> > >`, that is, a vector containing pairs of ints to vectors. ( I know I could acheive the same thing with a map, but that's not what I'm asking )

How would I search for the int (the one in the pair) using STL? I wrote a solution that works:

```
struct FindFirst {
    FindFirst(int i) : toFind(i) { }
    int toFind;
    bool operator() 
        ( const std::pair<int, std::vector<int> > &p ) {
            return p.first==toFind;
    }
};
```

That can be used like this:

```
int valueToFind = 4;
std::find_if(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), FindFirst(valueToFind));
```

But it looks to me like this a little ugly; there must be a better way.
So are there **better** ways of doing  this **without** using anything from C++0x or Boost?
(Because I'm trying to learn the best way of doing it with, and I stress, only **STL**)

EDIT:
Looks like there's a little confusion on what I'm asking. What I'm more interested in is whether it's bad practice to use the constructor for search values on a functor, especially when they are used in STL algo's.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot hold this question back: Why are you not using a map for this?

Comment: I have come across the same problem before in multiple ways; this is just the best example I can come up with for the moment that requires a functor like this.

Comment: If you find that ugly, then you are only starting to learn c++ :)

Comment: It's not ugly in the sense that it's **visually** ugly; I think it's ugly because there must be a **better** way of doing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the best way to do it, when using only the STL. What exactly do you not like about it (except maybe it's verbosity)?

It is versatile, because you can use with other algorithms like for instance `std::binary_search`.

It is quite simple and direct (at least to someone used to C++ functors).

The only thing to really improve here would be the choice of the data-structure. Such use-cases are covered by `std::map`, and you have not explained why you cannot use it. I understand that for your real problems a map really might not be suited, but in that case your example is not representative of your actual problem. You should fix that.

Comment: The only thing is, I thought there might be some way to pass the search value to the call operator using `bind2nd` or similar

Comment: @Schnommus: Sadly, there is not. This shortcoming was addressed in C++0x with the introduction of lambdas.

Comment: That is the answer I was looking for - I was looking through the docs of `<functional>` and I was sure there might be a way... Guess not.

Answer (score 1):

why not using direct STL calls

```
void FindFirst(std::vector<std::pair<int, std::vector<int> > >& v, int intToLookFor)
{
   std::vector<std::pair<int, std::vector<int> > >::iterator iItr;
   for (iItr = v.begin(); iItr != v.end(); ++iItr)
   {
       if (iItr->first == intToLookFor) return;
   }
}
```

(Sorry for the variable names ;-)).
Also the return value from this function can be an iterator, or a reference to the vector value...

Comment: To make this a good, canonical approach, this should be a function template that uses iterators to specify the range in which to search. However, the advantage of the OPs approach is, that his functor can also be used with other algorithms, like for instance `std::binary_search`, if the sequence is ordered appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a bad practice to pass a parameter to the predicate function. Actually, that makes the predicate quite flexible.

Alternative is to use global variable - which I would call a bad practice to use for predicate.

Comment: Another alternative is to define a global `bool operator==(const std::pair<int, std::vector<int> > &left, int right)`, but IMHO this is in no way an improvement over the OPs approach.